# Android push disappears after a few seconds

Tags: android, push-notification

My test phone is a Samsung Galaxy S6 using Android 7.0 Nougat.

In other apps, Android push notifications stay in the status bar, but in my app the push notification disappears after the notification is received.

Problem is DISAPPEAR NOTIFICATION FROM STATUS BAR.
Not about NOTIFICATION ALARM.
Push notification is well done working.
After ringing, there is no push in status bar.

Does anyone know about this situation?

Here is the code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_noti)
.setContentTitle('My App')
.setContentText('test')
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
.setAutoCancel(true);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 
0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

If someone knows about this issue, please answer.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly (except for the single quotes here `.setContentTitle('My App')` and  here `.setContentText('test')`)!

Maybe there are some system issues - or maybe this behavior is caused by some other part of your app.

By the way, note that `NotificationCompat.Builder` is deprecated; now it requires an additional String `channelId`.

Comment: It work perfectly means, nougat s6 Status bar have still push text? or just alarm?
push noti is well done for me too, but problem is after alarm status bar have still app push but there is no push in status bar.

And we have to fix the targetSDKversion, so maybe more days or weeks ago we'll change notificationCompat. Thanks for that.

Comment: I can't understand your problem completely - for me it works as expected. Notification is shown for a few seconds on the screen, than it appears in the status bar and remains there until clicked or dismissed. For different behavior maybe you should alter `Notification.PRIORITY`. Or maybe you share some screenshots?

Comment: Basically, After notification, in status bar have Push contents(app icon, app name, push message). right?
But my app push contents is disappear after notification. For a moment before notification, In status bar have push contents but after notification that is gone..

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the problem was that I had two different notifications with the same id.

One was tied to a service so when I unbound the service it killed the notification but since both had the same ID it killed both notifications.

Changing the notification id when calling the notify method fixed the issue:

```
notificationManager?.Notify(2, notification); //Previously I had "1" which matched another notification that had 1 as ID
```

Took me like 4 hours to find out but at the end in my scenario it had nothing to do with the notification settings.